# how to keep the code running when element is not found

Tags: java, selenium

hi there my code keep running an error when this element is not found

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='_soakw coreSpriteLikeHeartOpen'])")).click();
```

can anyone help me?  i want the other code to keep running even though this element is not found  I've been looking for the answer the whole day on the internet

Comment: If your question is answered to your liking please consider marking one of the answers as the answer: [How to mark a question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: @Thomas That's unethical. Ask OP to gather more Reputations and offer a bouty on the Question. Thanks

Comment: there are two answers, the OP can chose one. this way the question is marked as answered and it will be easier for reference material. Thatis my motivation behind my commend.

Comment: this is basic core java concept. please read the books before jumping to automation.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a `try catch` block around the find element. After the catch blok the execution of the code wil continue.
The function findelement throws a NoSuchElementException when there is no element found.

```
// Set the timeout for searching an element
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try 
{
    // Try to find the element
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='_soakw coreSpriteLikeHeartOpen'])")).click();
} 
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
    System.out.println("Element Not Found");
}
// Continue
```

Let me know if it worked or if you need anymore help.

Comment: hi there this is my code i ve tried your code but it doesnt work

    while (true){
        for (int i = 13 ;; ++i) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b'])
    [" + i + "]")).click();
      try{
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie){
    }
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='_soakw 
    coreSpriteLikeHeartOpen'])")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Close'])")).click();
    }  
}
    }
    }

Comment: What kind of exception are you having? in the code example you are note catching the `NoSuchElementException ` for the find element. or is this a question about some other part of the code??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way too :

```
List<WebElement> element= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='_soakw coreSpriteLikeHeartOpen']"));

if(element.size()>0)
{
    System.out.println("Found");
}
else
{
        System.out.println("Not Found");            
}
```

Important :

> **`FindElement()`** : It throws a NoSuchElementException exception when it
>   fails to find If the element.
>
> **`FindElements()`** : If the element doesn’t exist or not available on
>   the page then, the return value will be an empty list.